# Relation between polarization and susceptibility for nonlinear processes

Tags: optics, polarization, non-linear-optics, photonics

I've been confused about this for a while--
Boyd mentions that the second order polarization is related to second order optical susceptibility as $P_i(\omega_m + \omega_n) = \epsilon_0\sum_{(mn)}\chi_{ijk} E_j(\omega_m)E_k(\omega_n)$ where $\omega_m + \omega_n$ is fixed. Then he says that this expression can be re-written as $D\epsilon_0 \chi_{ijk} E_j(\omega_m)E_k(\omega_n)$ where "$D$ is known as the degeneracy factor and is equal to the number of distinct permutations
of the applied field frequencies $ω_n$ and $\omega_m$". Now I have the following questions:

1. In the above expression, I believe that $D$ can only be $1$ or $2$, for $\omega_m = \omega_n$ and $\omega_m \neq \omega_n$ respectively. Is this correct?
2. If the field has frequencies say 1,2,3,4,5. Then as per the first expression, we can have $P_i(5) = \epsilon_0\chi_{ijk} (E_j(1)E_k(4) + E_j(4)E_k(1) + E_j(2)E_k(3) + E_j(3)E_k(2) + E_j(0)E_k(5) + E_j(5)E_k(0) + others)$ , but according to the second expression, $P_i(1 + 4) = 2\epsilon_0\chi_{ijk} E_j(1)E_k(4)$. I'm not sure which one is correct.

Would be really helpful if someone could clear these confusions!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! I took a quick look at Boyd. I might be wrong but I have the impression that in the degeneracy expression he assumes the case of monochromatic fields, as in the examples he gives in pp.20 (third edition). Because of course a field at frequency 5 can be driven by 1+4, 2+3, etc frequencies and there is no reason, in principle, for 1+4 to be preferred over the others. If I understood correctly the question.